# Can I put a password on the folder I created with File Manager?

Tags: swift, file-manager, file-security

`resourceValues` I can access the information of the folder I created with resourceValues. I wonder if the folder I created later password.

How can I use `fileSecurity`? Is it ok to use fileSecurity ?

[image]

**Create Folder:**

```
func createNewDirectory(addPath: String, myFile: MyFile) {
    guard let mainURL = takeMainDirectoryURL(addPath: addPath, myFile: myFile) else {
        return
    }
    let path = mainURL.path
    
    do {
        try manager.createDirectory(atPath: path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error Description: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

**Get Folders:**

```
func takeArrayOfItems() {
    let foo = foo()
    var infoFile = [MyFile]()

    do {
        for url in foo {
            let resources = try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.creationDateKey, .nameKey, .fileResourceTypeKey, .contentTypeKey, .isDirectoryKey, .isHiddenKey, .customIconKey, .effectiveIconKey])
            infoFile.append(MyFile(fileName: resources.name ?? "", fileExtension: "", textForFile: "", image: nil, typeOfFile: resources.contentType?.preferredFilenameExtension ?? "emptyFolder", isLock: resources.isHidden ?? false, folderIcon: .init(rawValue: resources.contentType?.preferredFilenameExtension ?? "emptyFolder") ?? .empty, fileCreateDate: dateToString(date: resources.creationDate ?? Date())))
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.arrayOfFiles = infoFile
    }
}
```

Comment: You can encrypt the data you're writing to files.

Comment: Can I encrypt with folder ?